# Xamarin - passing data from device specific code back to Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

All,
I have a Forms / iOS / Android project that among other things needs to retrieve geo location data from the device at certain intervals. After some research, I found the correct way to do this was using background services in IOS and Android rather than trying to do this in Forms. I've done just that and have both IOS and Android reporting lat / long info every X minutes by calling a method using the dependency service. So everything is working great as a concept.

Now I'm trying to wire everything up in the main PCL project and I'd like some advice on the best way to do this. For example, in iOS, I have an event handler for when the CLLocationManager object fires a location changed event. How can I let my Forms project know this and pass the new lat / long values to the parent project code? This is my first device-specific-code-heavy project so I'm in uncharted waters for me here.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: this would be a good use of MessagingCenter: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/

Comment: How did you call the dependency service in PCL project. I think you should get the lat/long value when you call the dependency service in PCL project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common scenario and it can be solved a few different ways. My personal preference is to follow the pattern used in the Xamarin.Forms Plugins. Take a look at how the [Geolocator Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) is structured:

```
// Abstraction for the information you want to access in shared (PCL) code
public interface IGeolocator
{
    event EventHandler<PositionEventArgs> PositionChanged;
    ...
}
```

Here, an event helps bring in a way for any PCL code using `IGeolocator` to subscribe to position updates. This sounds like what you are asking about with `CLLocationManager`. To forward this information along, the iOS specific implementation of `IGeolocator` raises the `PositionChanged` event when `CLLocationManager.LocationsUpdated` fires.

```
manager.LocationsUpdated += OnLocationsUpdated;
...

void OnLocationsUpdated(object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (CLLocation location in e.Locations)
        UpdatePosition(location);
    ...
}

// UpdatePosition copies the lat/long/etc into the PositionEventArgs and calls OnPositionChanged

void OnPositionChanged(PositionEventArgs e) => PositionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
```

Finally, it's used in shared code either with a singleton or using the `DependencyService.Get<IGeolocator>()`:

```
try
{
  // Singleton usage
  var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

  // DependencyService
  // var locator = DepedencyService.Get<IGeolocator>();

  locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

  // Subscribing to event in shared code
  locator.PositionChanged += OnPositionChanged;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  ...
}
```

All of this code can be found [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin). You might also consider using this Plugin too. It has some other functionality which you might find useful. The GitHub page shows how to get started with it.